# Google Sheets API strips out links

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I'm fetching some data from Google Sheets via Node, but the API only returns the text value when there's a hyperlink present. I've searched for solutions, and everyone seems to say to add `valueRenderOption: 'FORMULA'` to your API call, but that still doesn't do anything for me because it doesn't look like these links are applied via the `HYPERLINK` formula; the user is highlighting text, hitting CMD/CTRL + K, and creating a link that way because when I select the cell, the formula field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Looks like you can't use `spreadsheets.values.get` in this case. You have to use `spreadsheets.get` and pass `includeGridData: true`.